# Outlook plugin always showing "Plugin is working on your request"

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

We have installed an Outlook Plugin that is using "On Send Feature" of outlook. Now whenever we send simple email without using that plugin there is always a message showing "Plugin is working you your request" when clicking on Send Button of email.

Comment: Hey, The on-send feature is triggered by the ItemSend event type and is UI-less. Hence whenever you create a simple mail with the add-in installed, the UI-less add-in gets triggered. For more info, kindly check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#how-does-the-on-send-feature-work

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Is it possible to prevent that message from appearing or change the message?